# Operator overloading for Type

Tags: c#, operator-overloading

When I was typing the question I could see list of *Operator Overloading...* questions lined up. Most of them are either for C++ or Haskell. My question is for C# and one could say the logic could be the same. And my problem is I want to understand operator overloading in C# context.

I was looking at a tutorial and it shows,

```
DateTime dt1 = new DateTime();
//do some work
DateTime dt2 = new DateTime();
TimeSpan ts = dt2 - dt1;
```

And the author said, utilization of `-` within DateTime datatype is the best operator overloading example. All I can see is one date is substracted by another and save into a `TimeSpan` object. It is not using `operator` keyword and `static` keyword either.

I find it difficult to understand. Can someone explain what's going on here? Does it mean underneath the above `ts = dt2 - dt1`, there's a `public static DateTime operator -(DateTime, DateTime)` happening?

Update:

Second example:

```
//some parameterized constructor is here to set X, Y

public static Point operator +(Point p1, Point p2)
{   
    Point p = New Point();
    p.X = p1.X + p2.X;
    p.Y = p2.Y + p2.Y;
    return p
{
```

In this case operands have to be same type as return Type?

Comment: Look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288467(v=vs.71).aspx)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `operator` keyword is used when *declaring* the overloaded operator, not when *using* it.

So the operator would be written like this:

```
public static TimeSpan operator -(DateTime lhs, DateTime rhs)
{
    // Code to execute
}
```

None of that interferes when you *use* the operator - you just use it in the kind of code you've already shown. So this line:

```
TimeSpan ts = dt2 - dt1;
```

will invoke the code given above.

Sample code:

```
using System;

public class Int32Wrapper
{
    private readonly int value;
    public int Value { get { return value; } }

    public Int32Wrapper(int value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public static Int32Wrapper operator +(Int32Wrapper lhs, Int32Wrapper rhs)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("In the operator");
        return new Int32Wrapper(lhs.value + rhs.value);
    }
}

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Int32Wrapper x = new Int32Wrapper(10);
        Int32Wrapper y = new Int32Wrapper(5);
        Int32Wrapper z = x + y;
        Console.WriteLine(z.Value); // 15
    }
}
```

To answer the final bit of your question:

> Does it mean underneath the above `ts = dt2 - dt1`, there's a `public static DateTime operator -(DateTime, DateTime)` happening?

No - there's no `DateTime` subtraction operator which returns `DateTime` - there's just the one which returns `TimeSpan`.

EDIT: With regards to your second example with `Point`, I don't think it logically makes sense to add two `Point` values together. What would you get if you added your home location to your work location, for example? It makes much more sense to have a `Vector` type, and then:

```
public static Vector operator -(Point p1, Point p2)
public static Vector operator +(Vector v1, Vector v2)
public static Point operator +(Point p1, Vector v1)
```

Comment: @aspiring: No, but who said it has to be? The operator has to be declared in the type of one of the operands, that's all. (Or for a conversion operator, it can be in either the source or target type.)

Comment: ***The operator has to be declared in the type of one of the operands, that's all.*** This is indeed valuable info. Each of the example I see are showing the same Types for return type and operands.. Can I conclude in that case `TimeSpan` and `DateTime` rather special case? Where as my second example for `Point` follows same `return Type` as `operands`...

Comment: I got it. :) for e.g. if I want to get distance between two `points`, then I must return that distance as `double` type. 

`public static double operator -(Point p1, Point p2)
{
  return Math.Sqrt(p2.X - p1.X....);
}`

Comment: @aspiring: That would work, but it isn't what I'd do: I'd return a `Vector` as the more natural difference between two points. For the distance, you'd want the magnitude of the vector.

Comment: @aspiring: When you keep on updating your post to ask new variations on the question, it makes it hard to keep an answer straight and valid...

Answer (score 3):

Say you have a class "Amount", like this:

```
public class Amount
{
    public int AmountInt { get; set; }
}
```

And you have two instances of that class:

```
Amount am1 = new Amount { AmountInt = 2 };
Amount am2 = new Amount { AmountInt = 3 };
```

You cannot simply do:

```
Amount am3 = am1 + am2; //compilation error
```

You have to add an operator to the Amount class to provide this functionality:

```
public static Amount operator +(Amount amount1, Amount amount2)
{
    return new Amount { AmountInt = amount1.AmountInt + amount2.AmountInt };
}
```

Same goes for subtraction (-). Now if you do:

```
Amount am3 = am1 + am2;
```

the int-value property of am3 will be 5 in this case. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you, another decipherable example :)

Answer (score 0):

All an operator is, is syntactical sugar for a method.  for instance the - operator can be somethign resembling

```
//not the actual syntax
public MyObject minus(MyObject object1, MyObject object2)
{
    //insert custom subtraction logic here
    return result
}
```

---

You can overload operators for any custom class you define.

[here's a tutorial I found on you actually do it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288467%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Here's a relevant snippit from the first example of the tutorial

```
   // Declare which operator to overload (+), the types 
   // that can be added (two Complex objects), and the 
   // return type (Complex):
   public static Complex operator +(Complex c1, Complex c2) 
   {
      return new Complex(c1.real + c2.real, c1.imaginary + c2.imaginary);
   }
```